# CommandOnCooldown error handler not catching error! Have tested everything

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I have looked at the other questions similar the fixes are not working this is my code.

```
 @bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send("Command On Cooldown. Sorry fo rugly text. I will fix it - Kwuartz")
        m, s = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        d, h = divmod(h, 60)

        if int(h) == 0 and int(m) == 0:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1ABC9C)
            embed.title = "**Command Cooldown:**"
            embed.description = f"**Why this happened:**\nThis command is on a cooldown of **{int(s)} seconds** on a per user basis."
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        elif int(d) == 0 and int(h) == 0 and int(m) != 0:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1ABC9C)
            embed.title = "**Command Cooldown:**"
            embed.description = f"**Why this happened:**\nThis command is on a cooldown of **{int(m)} minutes** and **{int(s)} seconds** on a per user basis."
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        elif int(d) == 0 and int(h) != 0:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1ABC9C)
            embed.title = "**Command Cooldown:**"
            embed.description = f"**Why this happened:**\nThis command is on a cooldown of **{int(h)} hours**, **{int(m)} minutes** and **{int(s)} seconds** on a per user basis."
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1ABC9C)
            embed.title = "**Command Cooldown:**"
            embed.description = f"**Why this happened:**\nThis command is on a cooldown of **{int(d)} days**, **{int(h)} hours**, **{int(m)} minutes** and **{int(s)} seconds** on a per user basis."
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x1ABC9C)
        embed.title = "**Command Error:**"
        embed.description = f":x: **Why this happened:**\nThe command you specified does not exist."
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    else:
        raise error
```

PS: I am new so may have stupid mistakes. Sorry! I will attach more code if necessary

Console output:

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\PythonProjects\Atom\ImpulseBot\main_setup.py", line 158, in on_message
await bot.process_commands(message)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 940, in process_commands
await self.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 907, in invoke
await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 422, in dispatch_error
await injected(cog, ctx, error)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 71, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\PythonProjects\Atom\ImpulseBot\cogs\moderation_commands.py", line 225, in clear_error
raise error
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
await self.prepare(ctx)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 785, in prepare
self._prepare_cooldowns(ctx)
File "C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 773, in _prepare_cooldowns
raise CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown: You are on cooldown. Try again in 9.53s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the time in the format `hours, minutes, seconds,` then you can use the modulo operator to your advantage:

```py
d = math.floor(error.retry_after / 60 / 60 / 24) 
h = math.floor(error.retry_after / 60 / 60) 
m = math.floor(error.retry_after / 60) 
s = error.retry_after % 60
```

If the `on_command_error` is not catching everything, it's because it only applies to *command* errors.

PS. Please specify your problem so it is easier to fix.

This is what my code was when it worked:

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    retryAfter = [math.floor(error.retry_after / 360), math.floor(error.retry_after / 60), error.retry_after % 60]
    await ctx.send('You cannot use command `%s%s` for %s hours, %s minutes, and %.2f seconds.' % (
    str(bot.command_prefix), str(ctx.command), retryAfter[0], retryAfter[1], retryAfter[2]))
    print('Command "%s" is on a %.3f second cooldown' % (ctx.command, error.retry_after))
```

Comment: It was working as an error before and I have seen many people classify it as an error. I get the CommandOnCooldown thing in the console but my error handler isn't triggered. It says discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown. So it is classified as an error.

Comment: Does `commands.CommandNotFound` work? Does the problem only apply to `CommandOnCooldown`?

Comment: No the error does not get catched. I have tried making a cooldown specific for every comamnd that has a cooldown and that works but I want to make a global one.